# Portable Database for Application

Tags: c#, database

I used Sql Server *2005* and *2008* until now, and for portability i used Access. I have heard about Sql Compact edition, and read its max supported size is *4GB*, is there any way to increase the max size? Or there are alternate databases for doing the same job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) RDBMS

- **Full support of Stored Procedures and Triggers**
- **Full ACID compliant transactions**
- **Referential Integrity**
- **Multi Generational Architecture**
- **Very small footprint**

Comment: Thank you. I was waiting for more suggestions, as there are only two so i considered them the best.

Answer (score 1):

For relational databases, you might look into [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  There is an ADO.Net provider for it [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org).

If you're interested in a great NoSQL database, I highly recommend [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/), which includes an embedded mode.